# Doctrine - mapping an entity from an external library

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm

i'm using an external library (the awesome [nicmart/Tree](https://github.com/nicmart/Tree) to build trees) that returns me an object that is the extension of the original object produced by the library

```
class originalObject
{
   //some properties
   // this is the object produced by the library
   // i dont want to modify the external library so no mapping here
}

class myObject extends originalObject
{
   //this is the entity i want to persist
   // but it hasnt got any property ??

 }
```

i want to persist `myObject` with Doctrine\MongoDB, therefore i need to map it.

i (obviously) dont want to modify the library itself so my question is:

> where do i put the mapping ?

I thought i could override the properties (like i would do with methods) by re-declaring them and adding the mapping to the re-declaration, but they are not overriden but duplicated.

Comment: Just use an external mapping type like YAML or XML and add it explicitly in your config (see http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMongoDBBundle/config.html#mapping-configuration)

Comment: IMO this is the correct answer, but i cant mark it as such in a comment...

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you can't do it this way. You'll have to modify originalObject (add annotations there) or you'll have to declare whole myObject and can't inherit origObj.